# Border appearing the text color of an anchor on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border

On Google chrome, if I have a `div` within an anchor, randomly the border will change to the text colour.  If I inspect the element, the colour switches back instantly to the proper colour.  Is there a way I can get around this error?

This is the html: (it doesn't happen every time, spontaneously it will be the wrong colour)

```
<a href="/about"><div class="navc">
    <div class="navt"><?php echo $lang['0']; ?></div>
</div>
</a>
```

this is the css:

```
#nav
{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:30px;
background:url('../images/nav.png') repeat-x;
border:1px solid #C2C1C1;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 white
}

#nav a
{
color:black;
text-decoration:none
}

.navc
{
padding:0 10px;
border-left:1px solid #C2C1C1;
border-right:1px solid #EEE;
float:left;
height:100%
}

.navt
{
padding-top:6px
}
```

As can be seen on the following image,the border of the About navigation button is wrong

[image: border error]

Comment: You have given neither the `.navc`, nor the `.navt` rules...

Comment: OK, what is the computed style of the enclosing `A`? Does it have any borders or outlines? Is it by chance `:visited`? You can find these out using the Chrome DevTools (in the `Styles` pane header on the right, click the dotted-rectangle-and-pointer button with the `A` selected, select `:visited` to emulate the `A:visited` style).

Comment: It says it computed border colours as black from this line at the beginning of my css page `*{ margin:0;padding:0;border:0}` to remove the initial borders on the page.  However that is in the computeded styles pane, in the normal styles pane, there is no other border color shown.

Comment: Can you put the final page with the CSS up on http://jsfiddle.net so that people can play around with it and inspect it? It is very hard to use a delayed channel of communication in such a kind of debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

Only took me 3 hours to solve this bug (on days like this I feel like Webkit is just as bad as Trident)... but here's the answer:

It only occurs when you have an inline elements inside an anchor `(<a>)` with a "href" value that has been visited. Such as:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><span>Button</span></a>
```

To fix the issue, I added the following CSS:

```
a {color: blue}

a span,
a:visited span /* Webkit will render a blue border unless this is explicitly specified */
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,

if I use a `span` instead of a `div`, the issue doesnt seem to occur.

edit - it occurred once since its been a span, refreshed and it hasn't occurred since.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this with some markup like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="outer-link">
    <img src="http://google.com/gif.png" />
</a>
```

My styles looked like this:

```
img { border: 2px solid gray; }
```

The gray border was getting turned into the blue link color, here is how I fixed it:

```
.outer-link { color: gray; }
```

So even when the img is getting the wrong border, it's defaulting to the gray border color that I specified.  I know it's a bit hacky but it works.